# How to call an imported module?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

for example before

```
var module = require('module');
```

using `es2015`

```
import module from 'module';
```

but if

```
var module = require('module')();
```

how should I write using `es2015` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it in two parts:

```
import module from 'module';
const instance = module();
```